# Why multiple Akka Actors prevent message lost?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm recently testing difference Akka message processing module, and I found an interesting phenomenon. Basically I compared two situations:

1) Single actor with Future to process message. 
2) Multiple actors with single thread for each.

From performance's view, I didn't found too much difference. But I found the first solution has higher chance to lost data if the mailbox capacity is very limit. For example I have 8 threads in the pool, and 16 message paralleled sending and the message queue capacity is 1, for the first solution, I will lost most of them from the second 8 messages, but for second solution, 8 actors can handle all the 16 messages(some times only lost 1 or 2).

Does that means actor will cache the next message while it is processing the current one?

```
import java.util.Calendar

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorRef, ActorSystem, DeadLetter, Props, Terminated}
import akka.routing.{ActorRefRoutee, RoundRobinRoutingLogic, Router, RoutingLogic}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Example_6_Backpressure extends App{
    lazy val akkaSystemConfiguration = ConfigFactory.parseString(
        """
          |akka.actor.default-mailbox {
          |  mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox"
          |}
          |
          |akka.actor.bounded-mailbox {
          |  mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"
          |  mailbox-capacity = 1
          |  mailbox-push-timeout-time = 100ms
          |}
          |
          |akka.actor.default-dispatcher {
          |  type = Dispatcher
          |  throughput = 100
          |  executor = "fork-join-executor"
          |
          |  fork-join-executor {
          |    parallelism-min = 1
          |    parallelism-factor = 1    # 8 core cpu
          |    parallelism-max = 8
          |  }
          |}
        """.stripMargin)

    final case class PayLoad[T](msg:T)
    final case class Shutdown()

    object RouterActor {
        def apply(childProps: => Props, instance:Int = 1, rl: RoutingLogic = RoundRobinRoutingLogic() ) = {
            Props(new RouterActor(childProps, instance, rl))
        }
    }

    class RouterActor(childProps: => Props, instance:Int, rl: RoutingLogic ) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
        override def preStart() = log.debug(s"${self.path}: Pre-Start")
        override def postStop() = log.debug(s"${self.path}: Post-Stop")

        var router = Router(rl, Vector.fill(instance) {
            val actor = context.actorOf(childProps)
            addWatcher(actor)
            ActorRefRoutee(actor)
        })

        def addWatcher(actor:ActorRef): Unit = {
            val watcher = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Watcher], actor))
            context.system.eventStream.subscribe(watcher, classOf[DeadLetter])
        }

        def receive: Actor.Receive = {
            case t:Shutdown =>
                router.routees.foreach { r =>
                    context.stop(r.asInstanceOf[ActorRefRoutee].ref)
                    router.removeRoutee(r)
                }
                context.system.terminate()
            case p:PayLoad[_] =>
                log.debug(s"${self.path}: route to child actor")
                router.route(p, sender())
        }
    }

    class Watcher(target: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
        private val targetPath = target.path

        override def preStart() {
            context watch target
        }

        def receive: Actor.Receive = {
            case d: DeadLetter =>
                if(d.recipient.path.equals(targetPath)) {
                    log.info(s"Timed out message: ${d.message.toString}")
                    // TODO: ...
                }
        }
    }

    object ChildActor{
        def apply() = Props[ChildActor]
    }

    class ChildActor() extends Actor with ActorLogging {
        override def preStart() = log.debug(s"${self.path}: Pre-Start")
        override def postStop() = log.debug(s"${self.path}: Post-Stop")

        override def receive: Receive = {
            case msg => {
                Future {
                    println(s"${Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis} - [Thread-${Thread.currentThread.getId}] - ${self.path}: $msg")
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                }(context.dispatcher)
            }
        }
    }

    object BackPressureExample {
        def apply(): Unit = {
            val system = ActorSystem("testSystem", akkaSystemConfiguration)
            val rootRef = system.actorOf(
                RouterActor( ChildActor().withMailbox("akka.actor.bounded-mailbox"), instance = 1), "actor-router"
            )
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-1!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-2!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-3!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-4!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-5!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-6!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-7!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-8!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-9!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-10!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-11!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-12!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-13!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-14!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-15!")
            rootRef ! PayLoad("Hello-16!")
            Thread.sleep(5100)
            rootRef ! new Shutdown
            Await.result(system.terminate(), 10 second)
        }
    }

    BackPressureExample()
}
```

The code shows single actor with multiple thread scenario, free to comment out "Future" from ChildActor and set instances parameter of RouterActor to 8 to experience multiple actors one.

Comment: What do you think "queue capacity" means?

Comment: You just remove the Future? Or the Thread.sleep too?
Remember that your are scheduling your futures in the same dispatcher used to run actors. So you are sleeping in the same threads used for receiving messages.

Comment: No, DON'T remove `sleep`, I want simulate `SLOW` processing, to observe message flooding, my goal is not handling all the message, contrast, I want understand why it doesn't happened!(in multiple actors solution.) I want understand why 8 `SLOW` actors can handle 16 `FAST` messages?

Answer (score 0):

Your test is a bit weird, I can't understand what are you trying to test here with a mailbox with size 1.

Each actor can handle one message at the time, so is expected that scenario (1) lost messages because actor will be busy with that message when a new message arrives and if queue is filled it will drop messages.

What was your expected behavior in scenario 1?

Comment: My expectation is the multiple actors or thread will pickup the message as quick as possible, because if them don't, message will flooding. the problem is the first solution matches to my expectation, but the second not.

Comment: Single actor solution picks up first batch of 8 messages quickly enough until the pool is exhausted, so the second 8 messages lost. that's the goal of testing. But the multiple actors one, when 8 actors were processing the first 8 messages, no other hands to handle the second 8 messages, I expected they will lost as same as  8 threads did, but actually it didn't happened!

Comment: The code shows single actor with multiple thread scenario, free to comment out "Future" from ChildActor and set `instances` parameter of RouterActor to 8 to experience multiple actors one.